# Digital SPDT switch

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, transistors, switches, netduino

I know this is probably a stupid question but I am hobbyist and could not find a solution to this problem.

I have a micro-controller that sends a PWM signal to a transistor that lets current flow through a coil in one direction but I want to be able to change the direction the current flows in every time I send a digital output from another pin on the micro-controller. For that I will have to use another transistor that can let current flow in the other direction.

My problem is that I need a way to switch to which transistor the PWM signal is send to by sending a pulse from a another pin. I am guessing that I will need some sort of digital SPDT switch. Is there anything like this any reference to a component or circuit will help.

Comment: The usual way of driving a coil (normally motors) in two directions is called an "H-bridge". Otherwise, you could do it with a few NAND gates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A two input H-Bridge made out of 2 NPN inputs, with the motor drive made out of 2 NPN & 2 PNP transistors and 4 diodes.

[image]

The specific transistors you use would be rated for your coil, doesn't have to be those specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you would still like to use your original approach, it sounds like a SPDT relay would work. Here is a [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/418/ENG_SS_108-98007_F%5B1%5D-205062.pdf) for one I use often.

There is a control pin which allows you to digitally select between one or the other, but since you are using a microcontroller you will have to drive it with a relay driver circuit like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [comcast.net](http://home.comcast.net/~tomhorsley/hardware/cellphone/phonetale/relay.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given a necessary current but you could also search for "analog multiplexers" that are basically just SPXTs

http://www.vishay.com/docs/72308/dg2714.pdf

That's an example.